# What is the Python equivalent to PHP's $_GET?

Tags: php, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, bottle

I was passing values from jQuery's `.getJSON()` to a PHP file with:

**jQuery**

```
<script>
function loadContent(href){
    $.getJSON("http://path/to/file.php", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(results){
        $("#my_div").html("");
        $.each(results, function(key,value){
            $("#my_div").append(value.content);
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$href = $_GET['cid'];
```

This meant that I could work with the `href` value passed from jQuery to the PHP file via [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) in the PHP file.

I've switched my app over to Python and wondering what the Python equivalent is to:

```
$href = $_GET['cid'];
```

The new environment is MongoDB, PyMongo and Bottle.  Bottle I believe is using `wsgi`.

I've seen a few references to an implementation like:

```
href = request.GET['cid']
```

Would this be the best way to do it/does this work (it's hard to test)?

**Update:**  The above doesn't work.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how I can test if the Python file is grabbing the value from jQuery? I can't `alert` from the Python file, is there an equivalent?

Comment: can't you write a jquery call that just `alert()` the response?  and have it return what you read?

Comment: To do that, I need to return the value of `href` back to jQuery, which means I need to encode it as `JSON` somehow, and I don't know how to do that.  I am using `import json`, `json_string = json.dumps(href)` and then `return json_string` but Firebug is showing the entire Python file as the `response` with `content type` of `text/plain`.  Because I am not sure if the following is correct:  `href = request.GET['cid']` , I am not sure if that is itself causing the data not to be returned to jQuery.

Comment: Please post the bottle code you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
from bottle import response, request
href = request.GET.cid # where 'cid' is the key name of the value you passed in, see original post for that implementation.
```

If you want to send the data back to jQuery in JSON format you can do this:

```
from bottle import response, request
from bson.json_util import dumps
href = request.GET.cid
# do things with variable here
response.content_type = 'application/json'
return dumps(your_variable)
```